# Regex in c# question

Tags: c#, regex

been trying the to figure out the escape char for "["and "]" in regex. I have the following pattern of string and this string is the actual string:

[somestring][anotherstring]

So the string will start with "[" followed by somestring and followed by with "]" and followed by "[" and followed by anotherstring and followed by "]".

can anyone please suggest?

Comment: I've found the free Rad Software Regular Expression Designer immensely useful when writing regular expressions. It includes a built-in reference and the ability to check your regex:

http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: btw, it would be helpful if you'd clarify whether you want a regex to validate/match the string or to extract/capture the two elements in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is only 1 level and you want to parse out the strings, then you do not need RegEx:

```
string composition = "[somestring][anotherstring]";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"][", "[", "]"};
string[] s = composition.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If you want to match for the exact pattern:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^(\[[^\[\]]+\]){2}$");
```

**Edit** - to answer with syntax-highlighted code to the commenter:
For parsing out the string Regex way using groups, you can use:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(composition, @"\[([^\[\]]+)\]"))
  Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: How do i extract the strings within the "[]"? so it will pull out somestring and anotherstring.

Comment: @ronald-yoh: Use the grouping operators.

Comment: I'm fairly new with regex.. can u please give me an example?

Comment: @leppie: +1.
@ronald-yoh: Added a Regex-way parsing to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
@"(\[[^\]]+\]){2}"
```

I think (my head hurts a little now).

Note, this will match anything between `[` and `]`.

Comment: Note: if the string is `[s[omest[ring][anotherstring]`, it will also match successfully, which you may not want.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the [ and ] with a '\'.

ie `"\[[A-Za-z]*\]\[[A-Za-z]*\]"`

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
This site is awesome for playing around with regexes.

Have Fun!

Comment: Note that you need to escape the backslash in the string (before the regex "sees" it) by using `"\\"` or `@"\"`.